# Customized Related List in Visualforce, suppress edit/delete buttons

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am fairly new to Visualforce and I have been trying to create a Related List in VF on object `Employee__c` to show all of the devices with an ‘Active’ status (`Status__c`  field on `Device__c` object).
There is a master-detail relationship on `Device__c` to `Employee__c`. The child relationship name is `Relatedemployees`.

I also tried to make sure the edit and delete buttons on the Related List do not appear.

Here are my codes:

Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Employee__c" extensions="ActiveDevices">
     <apex:detail relatedList="true">
         <apex:relatedList id="CustomList" list="Relatedemployees" title="Active Devices" 
                           subject="{!actDevices}">
         </apex:relatedList>

         <style type="text/css">
                .actionColumn {display:none; visibility:hidden}
         </style>
     </apex:detail>
</apex:page>
```

Class:

```
   public class ActiveDevices {
       public List<Device__c> getactDevices() {
           List<Device__c> actDevices = 
              [SELECT Name__c, Type__c, Serial_Number__c, Status__c,  
                 FROM Device__c WHERE  Status__c == 'Active' ];
           return actDevices;
       }     
   }
```

Comment: did you try: .actionColumn {display:none !important; visibility:hidden !important}

Comment: Jacob, can you explain what the issue you are facing ? are you not able to hide the action buttons ? or the list of records not being displayed as you expected ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<style type="text/css">
            th.actionColumn {display:none !important; visibility:hidden !important} 
            td.actionColumn {display:none !important; visibility:hidden !important} 
</style>
```